# Error in Vector Length

Tags: r, vector, simulation, p-value

I am trying to simulate pvalues in R.  I am simulating 20,000 test statistics, some from a central T distribution and then rest from a noncentral T distribution.  I am looping through various pi0 values which indicate the proportion of test statistics from the central T distribution.

However, when I loop through this pi0 vector, it's length is not always 20,000 which it should be.  The code is attached.  All of the output should read is 20,000, although some indices result in 19,999. Why am I having this problem?

Thanks in advance.  Here is the code:

```
## Proportion from central T
pi0vec = c(0.05,0.10,0.20,0.30,0.40,0.50,0.60,0.70,0.80,0.85,0.90,0.95,0.975,0.99)

## Looping through pi0 values
for(i in 1:length(pi0vec)){

  ## Specifying pi0
  pi0 = pi0vec[i]

  ## Appropriate sample sizes
  nH0 = 20000*pi0
  nHa = 20000*(1-pi0)

  ## Generating pvalues
  null.tstats = rt(n=nH0,df = 10,0)
  alt.tstats = rt(n=nHa,df = 10,-5)


  ## Lengths not right??
  print(length(null.tstats)+length(alt.tstats))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason you need to round:

```
 nH0 = round(20000*pi0)
 nHa = round(20000*(1-pi0))
```